# Simplifying Redundant Piecewise Cases

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, piecewise

I would like to perform a summation from $1$ to $M$ of a simple piecewise function.  For example,

```
a[i_] := Piecewise[{{a, i == 1}}, b];
Assuming[Element[M, Integers] && M >= 1, Sum[a[i], {i, 1, M}]]
```

For $M \geq 1$, the exact solution is $a - b + bM$.  With Mathematica, however, I get

$$
\begin{cases}
a & M\leq1 \\
a - b + bM & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

This is not wrong, but I would like to simplify out the redundant first case.  I cannot seem to find the correct set of assumptions and simplifications necessary to do this.

Comment: You may not find this satisfying, but `Sum[c[i], {i, M}] // Last` works.

Comment: `Simplify[Sum[a[i], {i, 1, M}], M > 1]`